# HP Pavilion connector identification

Tags: identification, connector, laptop

It is from an HP Pavilion x2 Detachable 12-b010nr 12" Laptop and I need to replace the connector, because one of the pins broke.

[image: photo of PCB and unidentified connector]

Comment: it seems to be stuck down with red goo. that might make it hard to change,

Comment: Appears to be Hirose DF57 or DF65, but you'd have to verify by measuring the pin-spacing exactly: measure the mm between the end pins, then divide by seven.

Comment: Not an easy one to replace. It looks like the broken pin is part of a 3 pin cluster connected together. Check the mating plug to see if that’s true. If so you could be lucky, and could test and see if it works without replacing that pin.